# Navigation not scaling

Tags: html, css

I am creating a simple navigation where an image is floated to the left and the ul is floated to the right. When I shrink the browser the ul to the right doesn't scale down with the browser, I have made a media query which makes the wrapper = 100% when it is below the wrappers width but this still doesn't seem to be working. Below i will link all my code:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Nav</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<nav>
    <div class="wrapper">
<img src="logo.png">
<ul>
        <a href=""><li>home</li></a>
        <a href=""><li>about</li></a>
        <a href=""><li>work</li></a>
        <a href=""><li>contact</li></a>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Again, this is probably just a small little mistake so I'm very sorry if it's a simple fix.

```
@media all (max-width: 960px) {
    .wrapper {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: ralewayb;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ralewayb';
    src:url(Raleway-Bold.ttf);
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}

nav > .wrapper > img {
    float: left;
}

nav > .wrapper > ul {
    float: right;
    display: block;
}

nav > .wrapper > ul > a {
    text-decoration: none;

}

nav > .wrapper > ul > a > li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 65px;    
    line-height: 60px;
    color: #303030;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: I doubt it's the actual cause of the problem, but you're closing `</nav></div>` in the wrong order

Comment: Your HTML is invalid...only `li` can be children of a `ul` Put the links **inside**  the `li`

Answer (score 1):

Your media query is wrong and it should be at the bottom to not be overridden :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: ralewayb;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ralewayb';
  src: url(Raleway-Bold.ttf);
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
nav > .wrapper > img {
  float: left;
}
nav > .wrapper > ul {
  float: right;
  display: block;
}
nav > .wrapper > ul > a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav > .wrapper > ul > a > li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 65px;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #303030;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="//lorempicsum.com/futurama/50/50/2">
    <ul>
      <a href="">
        <li>home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>about</li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>work</li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>contact</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```